# Python logging, change file owner

Tags: python, logging

I'm using WatchedFileHndler of python logging facility,
this handler watches if log file was changed (logrotate etc.) and reopens the file if changed.

My process runs as root.

I need to change file owner of the new created file by WatchedFileHandler every time WatchedFileHndler recreates the file.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Don't run processes as root, bad things will happen. Unless you are certain the process needs root privileges.

Answer (score 3):

There is some advice on how to apply ownership to a log file when using the simple file handler in this documentation:

https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging-cookbook.html#customizing-handlers-with-dictconfig

I followed that pattern to do something similar for a `TimedRotatingFileHandler` so I imagine it would work for a `WatchedFileHandler` but I have not tried that type specifically.

To begin with, I created a function similar but not identical to the one in the documentation:

```
def owned_file_handler(filename, owner=None, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    We need this so we can set ownership of the log files.
    See: https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging-cookbook.html#customizing-handlers-with-dictconfig
    '''
    if owner:
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            open(filename, 'a').close()
        shutil.chown(filename, *owner)
    return logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename, *args, **kwargs)
```

The idea is to do the work we need to do and then pass all the other arguments to the actual handler.

Here is how I then had to change the handler configuration in my dictionary:

```
         'file': {
+            '()': owned_file_handler,
+            'owner': ['www-data', 'root'],
             'level': 'INFO',
-            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
             'when': 'W0',
             'backupCount': 8,
             'filename': f'/var/log/django/django_{name}.log',
         },
```

I replaced the `class` with a callback `()` to my own function (which will call the class directly) and I added the new `owner` argument. It is working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, there almost never is reason to run a service as root. This almost always is a security problem. Other than that, Python's os module provides what you need:

```
os.chown(path, uid, gid)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html